# How to return jsp with custom ErrorController?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to return a custom error page. Following [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page), I've created my error controller like so:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorResource implements ErrorController  {

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public Response handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("error handler called");
        try {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            return Response.ok(new Viewable("/path/to/jsp", model)).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown: " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, instead of a white label error page like:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 06 19:02:36 PDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

I instead see this:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

null
There was an unexpected error (type=null, status=null).
```

In a my normal files, I can return a jsp just fine. For example, the following works fine for me:

```
@Path("/")
public class Resource {

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @GET
    @Path("/swift/containers")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Produces({ "text/html" })
    public Response getContainersPage() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("containers", getContainers());
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/path/to/jsp", model)).build();
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that the method gets called because "error handler called" gets printed. No exception message gets printed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Also, when I change the Viewable path to some random, incorrect path, no error message gets printed and I get the same Whitelabel Error Page with null values

Answer (score -1):

I guess you didn't disable error whitelabel property or didn't add thymeleaf dependency in your pom.xml
Did you update

your application.properties like this ?

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

and pom.xml like this ?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Since I am already intercepting the /error call, I don't believe the whitelabel page disable is needed. When I disable it, I just get my classic 500 internal server error (I think the default error page for Tomcat).

Adding the Thymeleaf dependency, I can get the custom .html page to work, but this is simply different from the .jsp pages I've been using, and I would like to keep my logic consistent if possible.

Comment: He is not using thymeleaf, but jsp